# How to update Masonry on Vue.js 3 updated() lifecycle hook?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, bootstrap-5, grid-layout, masonry

I have a question regarding the Masonry layout update. How can I trigger it in the Vue.js (Version 3) lifecycle hook "updated()"?

I have a card grid view like in the following code (using Bootstrap 5 here), but struggle to update the Masonry layout when e.g. a card changes its size. I know that I can use layout() [see documentation](https://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html) but I don't know how to call it in my example.

**So my main problem is, that I don't know how to make my Masonry object accessible in the updated function when initialized in the mounted() function. How do I do that?**

```html
<template>
  <div
    class="row justify-content-left"
    data-masonry='{"percentPosition": true }'
  >
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xxl-3 mb-4 card-col">
      <Card 1 />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xxl-3 mb-4 card-col">
      <Card 2 />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xxl-3 mb-4 card-col">
      <Card 3 />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xxl-3 mb-4 card-col">
      <Card 4 />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
[imports ...]

export default {
  name: "ComponentName",
  components: {
    [components ...],
  },
  mounted: function () {
    // initialize masonry
    this.$nextTick(function () {
      var row = document.querySelector("[data-masonry]");
      new Masonry(row, {
        // options
        percentPosition: true,
      });
    });
  },
  updated: function() {
    //-->how to call the relayout of Masonry here?
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: You don't save Masonry instance so you cannot access it later. It's a good idea to do the opposite for any third-party lib, not just Masonry

Comment: Hi Estus, thank you for your answer! What would be the best way to do that in Vue.js regarding this particular case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To cache a reference the resulting `Masonry` instance, just assign it to a property (you don't need reactivity on this instance, so attaching a property is fine):

```js
export default {
  mounted() {
    this._masonry = new Masonry(this.$refs.masonry, ⋯)
  },
  updated() {
    this._masonry.layout()
  }
}
```

However, you'll notice that the `this._masonry.layout()` call does not actually re-layout the masonry items (likely due to some limitation of the library). The only workaround I see is to recreate the `Masonry` instance, and then you no longer need to cache a reference to it:

```js
export default {
  mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(() => this.layout())
  },
  updated() {
    this.layout()
  },
  methods: {
    layout() {
      new Masonry(this.$refs.masonry, ⋯)
    }
  }
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-masonry?file=src/components/MyMasonry.vue)